What is it? Waveguide part- gold plated?
Ok- new to waveguide parts- I acquired a few of these in a box.  Appears to be gold plate on brass and copper- any help? I have been all over the internet

Is there any writing on it?

It looks like it could possibly be a stub tuner for impedance matching but someone with more experience can give you a more authoritative answer.

More photos are needed from different directions, at least 3: one which shows the interiors (sharp and well lit!) one which shows the shortest limb and its base and one which shows the biggest limb as disassembled to parts. Otherwise you get mostly guesses.

Thanks All! I am adding pictures- here is what I’ve got for you- top of the termination is engraved with 187-8 (So size is W187 but the -8?) the flange is stamped (yes stamped not engraved) “UG-149A/U 1190”.

I used one of them in college, in the microwave lab. It's an adjustable band pass filter for a microwave waveguide. We called it "trumpet filter", but I don't know if it's an official name. I see it called a "post filter". It does look like a trumpet, doesn't it?
Wikipedia as a picture of a similar looking one.

A guess: It's an adapter which connects coaxial cable and waveguide. The coaxial connector end may have also a microwave rectification diode which generates a DC voltage to the coaxial cable. The existence of the diode is only a possibility, the photo doesn't prove nor deny it. Adapters with a diode are needed for example to detect how strong the microwave signal is.
The screws are for tuning. One screw is generally not enough if the matching should be good (=low reflection) in a wider band than at a single frequency.
It can be also an oscillator or a reflective amplifier. The top connection is in that case the DC input for the microwave amplifier diode.
Or inside the wavequide there can be a termination resistor which dissipates the coming microwave and a thermocouple to measure the incoming power from the temperature rise.
Shiny surface finish and the red cap hint its a part of premium quality laboratory kit for microwave experiments. Gold plating would be useful electrically only inside the wavequide and on the facing surfaces of wavequide joint flanges. Those flanges (=choke-cover joint flange) are quite complex microwave parts which make good low reflection joints without high precision planar contacts.
Gold plating looks surely fine and prevents corrosion on exterior surfaces, but the actual reason for not using paint is not clear for me. I know it's unpolite to say it's not gold, so no comment from me about whether it is gold or not. Gold plated parts (golden interiors and exteriors, too; maybe it's easiest to let the whole surface to get the same treatment) are available for higher microwave bands, say 50 or 100 GHz or more, to keep the losses manageable, but the small flange screw holes hint this is for less than 10 GHz.
The operating frequency range of the waveguide can be seen from the dimensions of the rectangular (interior) cross-section of the waveguide. Check it here https://www.rfecho.com/rectangular-waveguide-sizes/ if needed.
The number of the joint flange screw holes hints it's heavy, probably made to work either on S or C microwave frequency band.

The external surfaces of microwave systems should obviously never be gilded but simply painted, so it follows that the one in the picture is the internal part of a microwave device, perhaps a cavity?

Copper or aluminium exterior surfaces do not need even paint to make the wavequide to work electrically (as long as the interior is clean). The screws are not especially handy if this is inside a a microwave cavity.

I think the pins are external to the cavity whose supports are tightly fitted to the walls with high precision.

Can you tell an application for a cavity which has interiors this complex? Where's the coupling between the waveguide and the cavity? AFAIK the cavities have simple geometries to make only a certain waveform possible.

Unfortunately I am not aware of this.
